# "Index was out of range" error with button in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

I have a GridView that is using a LINQ data source. In my Page_Load, I am doing

```
Using rah As New LinqDataContext(LinqConnectionString)
                GridView1.DataSource = From l In rah.Links _
                                        Where l.CategoryID = CategoryDropDown.SelectedValue _
                                        Order By l.Name _
                                        Select l.LinkID, _
                                        l.Name, _
                                        l.URL, _
                                        l.Comment, _
                                        l.QuickLink

                GridView1.DataBind()

End Using
```

So far it appears to work fine, and I can see records showing up in the GridView when I run the page.

Each row in the GridView has a Delete Button in the last column:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="del" Text="Delete Link" />
```

(I have also tried asp:button in a TemplateField and ItemTemplate)

My problem is, when the button is clicked, it fails on the first line of code in the event handler:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

Dim ID As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value.ToString
```

The error is "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.", so for some reason it is not passing the row index properly.

My GridView code is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="Grid" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="LinkID" CellPadding="5">

    <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName"  runat="server" Text='<%#: Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="URL">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperURL" runat="server" Text='<%#: Bind("URL")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# "../GoToURL.aspx?url=" & Server.UrlEncode(Eval("URL"))%>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblComment"  runat="server" Text='<%#: Bind("Comment")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quick Link">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuickLink"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuickLink")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="del" Text="Delete Link" />


    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Probably you mean _gridViewCommandEventArgs_ right?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake when I posted here. Should say "e AS GridView..."

Comment: Just to clarify - that was a typo when I posted. I have not yet solved my actual problem

Comment: Can you show me your page load event?

Comment: Why don't you use just [SelectedDataKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selecteddatakey(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: Tried SelectedDataKey and it falls over with a similar error :(

Comment: For more information, when I use an asp:Button instead, I am getting this error "Invalid postback or callback argument."

Comment: Piyush Khatri, I don't really want to post my whole page_load, it is quite long. Is there any thing in particular that I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

Your ButtonField doesn't have a CommandArgument property set; so CommandArgument would be empty or null, which isn't in that collection.  I think that DataKeys requires an integer (as it's an array) and command argument is a string, and you may experience a type conversion error too?

Comment: Hi. I tried using CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LinkID") %>' but Visual Studio 2013 tells me it is not a valid attribute of ButtonField

Comment: That is correct, you can't; I forgot about that. If you use TemplateField with an asp:Button in the template, then it should work with the binding to the CommandArgument property.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses, but I ended up figuring out the problem. It was in code that I had not posted here. This question can be deleted if you like.